# How to make matplotlib use backend that pulls in Gtk3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gtk, gtk3

I am using [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) python package to do some analysis. During the analysis, I am trying to draw some plot. However, that is throwing an error:

```
(ipython:2926): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I asked the developer about this and he told me this:

```
GTK 2 and 3 cannot be used in the same program. GTK 3 is used by graph-tool,
and it seems you are using a matplotlib backend that pulls in GTK 2. You
need to use another backend, e.g. GTK3Cairo.
```

I am not able to understand how to do this. I tried searching and I got few related questions on stackoverflow. However, they don't solve my problem. The [instructions](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) on the official matplotlib page are also unintelligible for me. Can somebody kindly help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in your home directory you create a directory '.matplotlib'
2. in this '.matplotlib' directory, you create a file 'matplotlibrc' with the single line:

   backend      : GTK3Cairo

I am not sure the white spaces matter, but anyway the case doesn't matter.

this is an official matplotlib solution. what do you mean by 'unintelligible': you did not understand it (in this case I hope this helps), or it didn't work ?

Comment: Even this procedure doesn't work for me. I keep getting an error.

Comment: So the default location has been changed to `./config/matplotlib`. Now it doesn't throw that error. However, when I try plt.show(), it is throwing "NotImplementedError"

Comment: there seems to be a known issue about this (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2976 for instance) but I t's quite old. is this your problem ?

Comment: according to this, Matplotlib can work with cairocffi but not with py3cairo ('To use the GTK3 backend with Python 3 you have to use cairocffi instead of pycairo'). But I'm afraid this means you have future hard time...